# How to make JAX-WS webservice respond with JSESSIONID (session id)

Tags: java, soap, weblogic, jax-ws, jsessionid

I am a newbie in web services. I have a JAX-WS service which I need to implement session mechanism for. The SOAP messages are transported over HTTP, we use WebLogic, so JAXWS application is deployed on WebLogic app server and the services are accessible from WSDL document.

I have @WebServiceProvider (class that implements Provider< SOAPMessage >)

Now when I fire a login request I want JSESSIONID session cookie to be sent back, but we don't want to use CXF or anything else, just so called Metro, which frankly I don't yet completely understand. We also do not want to make this a persistent cookie, so manually adding a cookie to the response header is also not an option. But that works, I tried it. I just do not understand why session cookie is not set up automatically.

I've been searching the web and trying many things for 4 days now, nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Nisa,
You mentioned SOURCE is to be used. but the code you posted in this thread uses HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING . Is it correct ?

Comment: according to documentation i found back then (dont have the links now) this is correct, but we decided to go with the solution of adding manually a cookie (setting expiration time to 0 makes the cookie non-persistent), that is good enough for us now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. The issue was in the way the bindings are used in WebServiceProvider implementation. If HTTP binding type is used then SOAPMessage cannot be used as a type for Provider. The correct solution here is to use Source (not sure if something else can be used too, didn't try), i.e.

```
package com.primavera.ws.jaxws.provider;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.Provider;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider;

@WebServiceProvider(portName="MyPort", serviceName="MyService", targetNamespace="http://mytargetlocation", wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/My.wsdl")
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@BindingType(HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING)

public class MyProvider implements Provider<Source> {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;


    public MyProvider()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request)
    {
        MessageContext mc = context.getMessageContext();
        HttpSession session =    ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
        if (session == null)
            throw new WebServiceException("No HTTP Session found");

        System.out.println("SessionID: " + session.getId());

        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are passing JsessionId from client to server in WS/REST call ? is it possible that I manage session in server side only and at client side i manage JsessionId for REST ?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, just accessing the HttpSession in your web service should be sufficient to set the session cookie in your response.

You can do this by injecting the WebServiceContext into your web service like so --

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext ctx;
public void webServiceMethod() {
     MessageContext mc = ctx.getMessageContext();
     HttpSession session =    ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
     if (session == null)
         throw new WebServiceException("No HTTP Session found");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I've tried it, as well as @ Stateful and @ HttpSessionScope annotations (without space). I mean session does exist, but when I monitor the request-response in tcpmon it doesn't show the jsessionid, so i can't catch it on the use side. and even when i'm using MAINTAIN_SESSION_PROPERTY, still next time SOAP server is called the session id is different, so basically it does not transport the session back to the client via HTTP. adding it to the SOAP message is an option but we don't want to do that, we want it to be transported back in a HTTP response.

Comment: this is pretty much how it's laid out in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm . are you using the same proxy for subsequent requests on the client side?

Comment: @NIsa -- Are you enabling httpsession on your client ? You do this by `((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);`

Comment: when implementing @WebServiceProvider you implement Provider<?> interface and it has only one method which is invoke(WebServiceContext context, SOAPMessage request), this method reads action from SOAPMessage and acts accordingly. Now, I do all that, context is annotated with @ Resource, and I am using the same proxy (by which I guess you mean the reference to the port), but when I debug and watch context on the server and read session id from within the HttpServletRequest of context, it is different every time, even though I set SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY to true.